# What is threading model in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, model, multithreading

ASP uses STA threading model while ASP.NET uses MTA. What does it mean ?

Comment: I think asp.net uses an STA model as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [nice discussion](http://www.allinterview.com/showanswers/23417.html).